# LED circuit with an AL1793

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current, 24v

I'm currently making my own light fixture, a multicolor Par light to be exact (and a few other types once this is successful). Now I'm trying to control a string of 6 multicolor LEDs. The circuit will run on 24 V and will be controlled by a RP2040 microcontroller.

Each LED I use can produce 6 colors, here's a table with its properties:

| COLOR | VOLTAGE | CURRENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 2.2-2.6 | 350mA |
| Green | 3.2-3.6 | 350mA |
| Blue | 3.2-3.6 | 350mA |
| White | 3.2-3.6 | 350mA |
| ORANGE | 2.2-2.6 | 350mA |
| UV | 3.2-3.6 | 350mA |

A little history on my problem for context:

I bought some Meanwell NLDD350H's in order to try it out, connected everything on the breadboard and it worked like a charm, even PWM was no problem. But they are too expensive as I want to build multiple light fixtures, and 1 fixture requires 6 of them at 5eu a piece.

Next up I tried it on a Diodes Incorporated BCR420UW6Q which works a little differently, this is where my problem starts. Where the NLDD had no problem driving a single LED for testing purpose, the BCR burned the single LED instantly. But when I connected seven 3.3 V white LEDs in series, all was fine (although max current I was able to get from it was 150 mA instead of 350 mA).

I then tried it on my 6 LED string, which had mixed results. Most LEDs were very dim even with PWM at max, but then I hit the orange LEDs.... The LEDs were very bright and my BCR started smoking instantly. I thought this was a voltage issue and that I have to match the total LED voltage to the supply voltage. For the Meanwell this seemed not to be a problem at all and I kinda expected the BCR to work the same(ish).

Below is a more visual representation from the documentation, and AL1793 with 3 LED strings. Just imagine there are 6 LEDs per color in series. And also the AL1791 is not there. VLED will be 24 V

[image: application circuit from AL1793 datasheet]
Image source: [Diodes Inc - AL1791/AL1792/AL1793/AL1794 datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL1791_1792_1793_1794.pdf)

While trying to look for solutions I stumbled upon the Diodes Incorporated AL1793 which can drive 3 LED strings at once. Which would be nice because I will only need 2 chips instead of 6. And this one also seems to have much more safety features built-in according to its docs.

But my concern with this chip still has to do with the 24 V supplied. Docs say that the AL1793 will handle the remaining voltage not used by the LEDs, and outputs it as heat. For the 3.2 V string I doubt it would be much of an issue because 6 x 3.2 = 19.2V, even higher when voltage goes up because of heat and also has some chip usage. With the red and orange LEDs I'm not so sure anymore, as 6 x 2.2 = 13.2 V which is not close to 24 V at all, but I can't add more LEDs. Will this burn up the chip just like the BCR? Or will the AL1793 behave more like the NLDD does?

From what I can read in the docs they use the following formula:

```
* PDmax (Maximum Power Dissipation of AL179x) = (160ºC Junction Shutdown Temperature - Ambient Temperature, e.g. 85°C) /
55°C/W = 1.364Watts
* PAmax (Power to be Absorbed by AL179x) = Σ(VLEDx * Current through the emitter string * Associated PWM Dimming DutyCycle) for all channels
* Thermal Management Guideline PAmax < Pdmax
```

So that would be 24 * 0.35 * 1 = 8.4 W, but that exceeds the 1.364 W by a lot so I must be reading this all wrong.

What am I missing here? Is this plan even going to work the way I'm trying it?

Comment: You can't drive even a single string of 3.2v LEDs at 350mA using that chip at 24v, so not a good choice. If you want to use a linear regulator, you need to make sure the LED voltage drop sums to very nearly the supply voltage. If you can't do that you need a switching regulator which can drive LEDs at a different voltage than the supply without dissipation as heat.

Comment: Okay, so please correct me if I'm wrong, what you're saying is that I can use the chip, I just need to add a switching voltage regulator on the input voltage so I can step down the voltage without losing it to heat. This way the AL1793 will be fine, and can operate at 350mA? Or do I need a whole other chip?

Comment: That is one option, but I would first look for a switching LED driver that could take 24v and then drive 350mA directly. There are many such chips, including some with 3 channels like the AL1793.

Comment: So I would be looking at something like a Texas Instruments LM3407MY/NOPB for example? It only has a single output but then I know I'm looking in the right direction if correct. Or an Analog Devices Inc LT3003EMSE for 3 outputs?

Comment: Yes, although one marketed for RGB control might be easier for your purposes.